# use criteria API to select * from where ... clause

Tags: jboss7.x, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I have two entities: `Session` and `Formation`. They have a common attribute `idFormation`. I want to select all sessions which have the same id as the formation using criteria API (the idFormation is the argument of my method) but at least I have an error and I don't know what is wrong.

Can some one help me please? It's the first time I use criteria API. I have done something like this in my `SessionDao` I have this declaration:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<Session> findById(int id){
    CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    Root e = cq.from(Session.class);
    cq.where(((CriteriaBuilder)em).equal(
               e.get("idFormation"),
               ((CriteriaBuilder)em).parameter(Long.class, "id"))
    );
    Query query = em.createQuery(cq);
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

in my facade implementation I have this:

```
@Override
public List<Session> findAllID(Formation formation) {
    int id = formation.getIdFormation();
    return sessionDAO.findById(id);
}
```

In the managed bean I just execute the method which is called by the commandButton:

```
public String sessionsByForm(Formation formation) {
    this.listeSessions = sessionFacade.findAllID(formation);
    return LIST_DES_DOCUMENTS;
}
```

I have this error:

```
09:39:11,911 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager cannot be cast to javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder
09:39:11,916 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component SessionDAO for method public java.util.List com.dao.SessionDAO.findById(int): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager cannot be cast to javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:139) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:204) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:306) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at com.dao.SessionDAO$$$view23.findById(Unknown Source) [CrudEJB.jar:]
at com.facade.SessionFacadeImp.findAllID(SessionFacadeImp.java:50) [CrudEJB.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at com.facade.SessionFacade$$$view22.findAllID(Unknown Source) [CrudEJB.jar:]
at com.mb.SessionMB.sessionsByForm(SessionMB.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager cannot be cast to javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder
at com.dao.SessionDAO.findById(SessionDAO.java:35) [CrudEJB.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:202) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 93 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important line in the stack trace is:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: 
  org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager cannot be cast to 
  javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder
```

These two types are incompatible therefore casting fails.

Try to replace `findById` method with:

```java
public List<Session> findById(int id) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Session> cq = cb.createQuery(Session.class);
    Root<Session> e = cq.from(Session.class);
    cq.where(cb.equal(e.get("idFormation"), cb.parameter(Long.class, "id")));

    return em.createQuery(cq)
             .setParameter("id", id)
             .getResultList();
}
```

Comment: thank you soo much @wypieprz for your help .. I have already try this but in this case I can't recupere the **idFormation** and then can't verify if the idFormation = **id** .. I don't know what can I do in this case..can you help me please

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get what is the nature of the problem. The JPQL version of the query would look as follows: `SELECT s FROM Session s WHERE s.idFormation = :id` so everything seems to be fine. Could you please describe more what's wrong with idFormation? Still an error?

Answer (score 0):

Please try by giving class object while creating CriteriaQuery

```
 CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Session.class);
  Root e = cq.from(Session.class);
```

Comment: Please refer code sample given in oracle tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html

Comment: thanks @JagKum for your help I follow the example in the tutorial but I don't have access to the feild : **idFormation** i don't know why?